# Graphs in Prolog programming

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I'm new to Prolog programming and i'm trying to check if a graph has eulerian circuits. I have the below graph representation and code:

```
 find_e_circuit(G, Circuit) :-
        member(V-_Edges, G), 
        find_e_circuit(G, V, [], RevCircuit),
        reverse(RevCircuit, Circuit),
        countEdges(G, S),
        length(RevCircuit,S)
        writeln("Found an eulerian circuit: ").
    
    find_e_circuit(G,V,SeenVs,Circuit) :-
      (   memberchk(V,SeenVs)
      ->  Circuit=[V|SeenVs]
      ;   member(V-Edges,G),
          member(Vedge,Edges),
          find_e_circuit(G,Vedge,[V|SeenVs],Circuit) 
      ).
    ?- find_e_circuit([1-[2],2-[3],3-[4],4-[1]],Circuit)
```

The above works using that graph but if i try with [1-[2],2-[3],3-[4],4-[1],5-[4]] it still outputs (Circuit = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]) but it shouldn't. The countEdges counts the number of edges in the graph. Can someone advise how can i correct the above so it will print fine? How can I check if every edge is visited exactly once ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `How can I check if every edge is visited exactly once ?` You keep a tally in a separate data structure.

Comment: Any idea how to do this? As i just started Prolog it's quite difficult  to do this and actually make it work fine since i don't know that many things on Prolog

Comment: Seriously. Just start reading every question with the [Prolog tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog), you will find hundreds of similar questions and answers.